# How do I Connect Backend Python Code with a GUI

Tags: python, callback, frontend, backend

I have created a few python codes and now I am looking to create a front end for it. As an example I am using the library Tkinter and a simple 'register-log in' app. However, is there any general information on how to go about connecting python code with a GUI? The following is the example I'm using to help the community grasp what I am asking.

```
import tkinter as tk


HEIGHT = 600
WIDTH = 700

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Tk.title(root, "Welcome")


def button_1_clicked(first_name_entry, last_name_entry, username_entry, password_entry, reenter_password_entry):
    final_str = 'First Name: %s \nLast Name: %s \nUsername: %s \nPassword: %s \nRe-Enter Password:%s' % (
        first_name_entry, last_name_entry, username_entry, password_entry, reenter_password_entry)
    print(final_str)


def clicked():
    print("function works")


canvas_1 = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas_1.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='black')
frame.place(relx=0, rely=0, relheight=1, relwidth=2, anchor='n')

label = tk.Label(frame, text="Welcome User", font=('Courier Prime', 22, 'bold'), bg='black', fg='white')
label.place(relx=0.75, rely=0.1, relheight=0.14, relwidth=0.6, anchor='n')

lower_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='black', bd=10)
lower_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.25, relheight=0.62, relwidth=0.75, anchor='n')

label_1 = tk.Label(lower_frame, bg='yellow', text="First Name", font=('Microsoft Sans Serif', 11))
label_1.place(relx=0.08, rely=0.1, relheight=0.062, relwidth=0.25)

first_name_entry = tk.Entry(lower_frame, bg='red', font=('Microsoft Sans Serif', 11), fg='white')
first_name_entry.focus_force()
first_name_entry.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.1, relheight=0.062, relwidth=0.45, anchor='nw')

label_2 = tk.Label(lower_frame, bg='yellow', text="Last Name", font=('Microsoft Sans Serif', 11))
label_2.place(relx=0.08, rely=0.195, relheight=0.062, relwidth=0.25)

last_name_entry = tk.Entry(lower_frame, bg='red', font=('Microsoft Sans Serif', 11), fg='white')
last_name_entry.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.195, relheight=0.062, relwidth=0.45, anchor='nw')

label_3 = tk.Label(lower_frame, bg='yellow', text="Username", font=('Microsoft Sans Serif', 11))
label_3.place(relx=0.08, rely=0.29, relheight=0.062, relwidth=0.25)

username_entry = tk.Entry(lower_frame, bg='red', font=('Microsoft Sans Serif', 11), fg='white')
username_entry.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.29, relheight=0.062, relwidth=0.45, anchor='nw')

label_4 = tk.Label(lower_frame, bg='yellow', text="Password", font=('Microsoft Sans Serif', 11))
label_4.place(relx=0.08, rely=0.385, relheight=0.062, relwidth=0.25)

password_entry = tk.Entry(lower_frame, bg='red', font=('Microsoft Sans Serif', 11), fg='white')
password_entry.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.385, relheight=0.062, relwidth=0.45, anchor='nw')

label_5 = tk.Label(lower_frame, bg='yellow', text="Re-Enter Password", font=('Microsoft Sans Serif', 10))
label_5.place(relx=0.08, rely=0.48, relheight=0.062, relwidth=0.25)

reenter_password_entry = tk.Entry(lower_frame, bg='red', font=('Microsoft Sans Serif', 11), fg='white')
reenter_password_entry.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.48, relheight=0.062, relwidth=0.45, anchor='nw')

create_account_button = tk.Button(lower_frame, bg='#A7BCD8', text="Create Account", font=('Microsoft Sans Serif', 12),
                                  command=lambda: button_1_clicked(first_name_entry.get(),
                                                                   last_name_entry.get(),
                                                                   username_entry.get(),
                                                                   password_entry.get(),
                                                                   reenter_password_entry.get()))
create_account_button.place(relx=0.38, rely=0.68, relheight=0.09, relwidth=0.27, anchor='nw')


label_6 = tk.Label(lower_frame, bg='black', fg='white', text="OR", font=('Microsoft Sans Serif', 12, 'bold'))
label_6.place(relx=0.42, rely=0.787, relheight=0.07, relwidth=0.2)

button_1 = tk.Button(lower_frame, bg='#A7BCD8', text="Login", font=('Microsoft Sans Serif', 12), command=lambda: clicked())
button_1.place(relx=0.38, rely=0.88, relheight=0.09, relwidth=0.27, anchor='nw')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()
```

When 'button_1' is clicked I want to open the following window:

```
import tkinter as tk


HEIGHT = 600
WIDTH = 700

app = tk.Tk()
tk.Tk.title(app, "Home Area")

canvas_1 = tk.Canvas(app, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas_1.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(app, bg='black')
frame.place(relx=0, rely=0, relheight=1, relwidth=2, anchor='n')

label = tk.Label(frame, text="Enter Credentials", font=('Courier Prime', 22, 'bold'), bg='black', fg='white')
label.place(relx=0.75, rely=0.1, relheight=0.14, relwidth=0.6, anchor='n')

lower_frame = tk.Frame(app, bg='black', bd=10)
lower_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.25, relheight=0.62, relwidth=0.75, anchor='n')

label_3 = tk.Label(lower_frame, bg='yellow', text="Username", font=('Microsoft Sans Serif', 11))
label_3.place(relx=0.08, rely=0.29, relheight=0.062, relwidth=0.25)

username_entry = tk.Entry(lower_frame, bg='red', font=('Microsoft Sans Serif', 11), fg='white')
username_entry.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.29, relheight=0.062, relwidth=0.45, anchor='nw')

label_4 = tk.Label(lower_frame, bg='yellow', text="Password", font=('Microsoft Sans Serif', 11))
label_4.place(relx=0.08, rely=0.385, relheight=0.062, relwidth=0.25)

password_entry = tk.Entry(lower_frame, bg='red', font=('Microsoft Sans Serif', 11), fg='white')
password_entry.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.385, relheight=0.062, relwidth=0.45, anchor='nw')

label_5 = tk.Label(lower_frame, bg='yellow', text="Re-Enter Password", font=('Microsoft Sans Serif', 10))
label_5.place(relx=0.08, rely=0.48, relheight=0.062, relwidth=0.25)

reenter_password_entry = tk.Entry(lower_frame, bg='red', font=('Microsoft Sans Serif', 11), fg='white')
reenter_password_entry.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.48, relheight=0.062, relwidth=0.45, anchor='nw')

app.mainloop()
```

Also I want to point out it is NOT good practice to use both 'pack()' and 'place()' together.

> So my question stands is there any general information on how to go about connecting python code with a GUI?

And in this case how do I connect the "main page/ register page/ first page" to the "second page/login page" by the use of my function 'clicked()' when the 'Login' button is clicked (button_1).

**Thank you for all the help it is appreciated**

Comment: I don't understand. `tkinter` is a GUI. Are you asking how to connect it to a client browser?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Divide your GUI in Toplevel(s)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *


class Gui(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Gui, self).__init__()

        self.btn_open_new_window = Button(self, text="Open a new window", command=self.open_new_window)
        self.btn_open_new_window.pack(pady=50, padx=150)

    def open_new_window(self):
        NewWindow(master=self)


class NewWindow(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.hello_label = Label(self, text="HELLO, I'M A NEW WINDOW!")
        self.hello_label.pack(pady=50, padx=150)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Gui()
    app.mainloop()
```

**Solution 2**

Divide your GUI in frames

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *


class Gui(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Gui, self).__init__()

        self.first_frame = Frame(self)
        self.first_label = Label(self.first_frame, text="I'm a label in the first frame")
        self.first_label.pack(pady=10)
        self.first_frame.pack()

        self.second_frame = Frame(self)
        self.second_label = Label(self.second_frame, text="I'm a label in the second frame")
        self.second_label.pack(pady=10)

        self.btn_frame = Frame(self)
        self.btn_previous = Button(self.btn_frame, text="<< previous", command=self.previous_frame)
        self.btn_previous.pack(pady=20, padx=10, side=LEFT)
        self.btn_next = Button(self.btn_frame, text="next >>", command=self.next_frame)
        self.btn_next.pack(pady=20, padx=10, side=LEFT)
        self.btn_frame.pack()

        self.frames = [self.first_frame, self.second_frame]
        self.frame_index = 0

    def next_frame(self):
        for frame in self.frames:
            frame.pack_forget()

        self.btn_frame.pack_forget()

        self.frame_index = self.frame_index + 1
        self.frame_index = self.frame_index if self.frame_index < len(self.frames)\
            else self.frame_index // len(self.frames)

        self.frames[self.frame_index].pack()
        self.btn_frame.pack()

    def previous_frame(self):
        for frame in self.frames:
            frame.pack_forget()

        self.btn_frame.pack_forget()

        self.frame_index = self.frame_index - 1
        self.frame_index = self.frame_index if self.frame_index >= 1 else 0

        self.frames[self.frame_index].pack()
        self.btn_frame.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Gui()
    app.mainloop()
```